# Import Pictures from Picasa in Motorola Xoom

Tags: android

I have written a simple code for importing images from any image-supported applications

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

The code works fine when importing images from gallery but as soon as i import image from the picasa in my motorola xoom. It returns null and force closes with `NullPointerException`.

Does anybody have any idea about this ?

Comment: where you get the `NllPointerException`?

Comment: after importing the picture on activityresult as a bitmap and using its properties i get NullPointerException.....

Comment: Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

String selectedImagePath = imageUtil.getPath(selectedImageUri,Main.this);

BitmapDrawable d =(BitmapDrawable)BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(selectedImagePath);

Now while accessing "d.getWidth", I get NullPointerException..

Answer (score 0):

ACTIVITYRESULT_CHOOSEPICTURE is the int you use when calling startActivity(intent, requestCode);

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == ACTIVITYRESULT_CHOOSEPICTURE) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    final InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    is.close();
  }
```